# Where is the python library installed?

Tags: python, install-from-source

When I try to do `./configure` over [AWN v0.4](https://launchpad.net/awn/) I get this error:

```
configure: error: in `/home/desktop/Software/avant-window-navigator-0.4.0':
configure: error: 
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
```

So *maybe* I can solve this adding the path of the python library to the command. But I don't know where is it.

See the full output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5612494/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This message is not asking for the python libraries themselves, it's asking for the headers to link against them. You can install then with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

You are probably lacking some other dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to find it in the following locations

`/usr/lib/`
`/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: I have the same output with both locations. It could be a problem originated by another thing. I don't know really

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation with VAMOS Automotive Simulator. The Python version was hardcoded in the configure file, so I had to install that version instead, in my case:

```
apt-get install python3.4-dev
```