# Configuring Python Development version installation

Tags: python

While installing [PSI4](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/psi4manual/4.0b5/external.html) on **Edit:** Ubuntu 13.10 (earlier Ubuntu 12.04), I'm encountering the following error:

```
configure: error: 
Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
============================================================================
 ERROR!
 You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
 for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them
```

**Installation line :**

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/psi4 --with-blas='-mkl' --with-incdirs=-mkl
```

**Possible duplicates:**

[Where is python library installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267565/where-is-the-python-library-installed)

**Similar problems:**

[Python error while configuring mesos on centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969687/python-error-while-configuring-mesos-on-centos)

[Error compiling a c++ with Python bindings using mingw and msys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768325/error-compiling-a-c-with-python-bindings-using-mingw-and-msys)

Another possible solution on [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1282304).

**What I've tried:**

I've install `python-dev` and `python2.7-dev` using `apt-get`. This is the solution mentioned in the first, second and fourth links. I still keep getting the same error.

**What I don't understand:**

1. Is the problem coming because of the 32-bit compiler and 64-bit python mismatch mentioned in the third link (Error compiling...mingw...)?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, how do I make the compiler use 32-bit python?

**P.S.** Maybe this is irrelevant, but the log (before the error) pertaining to python

```
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.6... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python include statements... -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7
checking for python linker flags... -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
checking consistency of all components of python development environment... no
configure: error:
```

Comment: Sure you _noted_ the note under "Python developer libraries correspo..." on [this page](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/psi4manual/4.0b5/installfile.html#sec-install-i)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Using `python2.7-config` returns `/usr/bin/python2.7-config --prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--configdir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related to the installation of the development package for python but since you decided to use Intel’s MKL library to build PSI4 you have to have them properly installed somewhere.

For a Linux compilation though you could select the ATLAS library as stated in the [Recommendations for BLAS and LAPACK libraries](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/psi4manual/4.0b5/installfile.html#iv-recommendations-for-blas-and-lapack-libraries):

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-dev
```

Then you'll be able to launch configure without any problem:

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/psi4 --with-blas='-lf77blas -latlas' --with-lapack='-llapack -lcblas'
```

Tested OK with [psi4.0b5.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/psicode/files/psi/4.0b5/psi4.0b5.tar.gz/download) on 12.04 LTS and 13.10.

Comment: Why can I not use the MKL library? I installed the MKL library just fine. And how did you understand what the issue was?

Comment: Where did you dowbload it, so that I can try it too?

Comment: It can be downloaded from Intel's website, you just to have sign an agreement for non-commercial use and you have to wait for 1-2 hours to get a mail. In fact, I was also planning to use the Intel Parallel Studio XE (download similarly) which installs MKL.